# How to remove borders in aura tree grid

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

i have an aura tree grid table that looks like below
[image]

I want to remove the lines between 2 rows i.e the borders of the table.
I am able to do it using the inspect in browser and then unchecking the 'slds-table_bordered' class.

[image]

But not sure how to do this in the aura component code.

Answer (score 0):

In your aura component, create a new file or modify an existing **[CSS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm)** file. Your **CSS** file should be named like `myTreeGrid.css`.

In the **CSS** file, use the `.THIS` selector to target your component and the `.slds-table_bordered` class to target the table. Then, set the **border** property to **none** to remove the lines.

For example:

```
.THIS .slds-table_bordered {
        border: none;
}
```